# Running mgr.Run() function on separate go routine - faktory/contrybsys

Tags: go, background-process

First timer using [Faktory](https://github.com/contribsys/faktory_worker_go) with Golang, and ran into the need of firing a job everytime the user hits an endpoint.

After registering the job, to make the job run you need to call `mgr.Run()` which is a function that does not return

```
    mgr := worker.NewManager()
    mgr.Concurrency = 1
    toRegister := map[string]bool{}
    mgr.Register(jobName, jobs.NewJob(apiCtx, jobFunc).PerformFunc())

    go mgr.Run()
```

currently I am adding a `go` to make it execute it in a separate goroutine, and it works fine.

Question is: Is it safe to do it this way? I am afraid it might be firing different processes that will never return, thus never end, and might crash the server at some point.

Comment: Check out this https://github.com/contribsys/faktory_worker_go/blob/8426a78d9920cede99ec47d073b50438ffbffb8e/manager.go#L124
That function is not meant to be called per request

I think you have to call `go mgr.Run()` before initialize your http server

Comment: Thanks, going with this approach makes way more sense